# Rename htaccess on Windows

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, localhost, xampp

I'm developing a website using xampp on my Windows computer. But when I try to rename the file `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` in order to enable rewrite rules in Joomla, I get an error message:

[image: File rename error]

How can I rename this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***In Windows Explorer***, the path of least resistance is to select the file then press `F2` to rename it (or right-click and choose *Rename*), then rename to:

```
.htaccess.
```

[image]

Notice the trailing dot (`.`), make sure you add that too. Hit enter and confirm that you want to rename the file and voila:

[image]

(I have a monkey head icon because I've got Helicon Tech's APE installed.)

Most of the Windows standard *"Save As"* dialogues will also let you save files named with a leading period this way as well provided you save as the type `All files (*.*)`.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of that little trick. I'll accept this answer as it is by far the simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Good answer provided by @Johanpw.

Personally, what I always do is open the `htaccess.txt` file in a text editor. For me, I tend to use **Notepad++** for simplicity.

Once done, simply go to **File** >> **Save As** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) and name the file `.htaccess`.

Job done

Comment: Another good option, I forgot about that. Note that if you use the regular Windows Notepad, you need to select "All Files" in the "save as type" field. If not, Notepad will add a `.txt` file type to the file.

Comment: Easiest option +1

Comment: Notepad++ reference +1, also; most IDEs can handle the renaming as well.  Notepad++ is also create for fixing corrupted file charset encoding which language definition files are picky about.

Answer (score 2):

**Background**
As the message confirms, Windows does not allow empty file names. The `.htaccess` file is used on Linux systems, and the dot (`.`) in front of the name is used to make it a [hidden file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94780/what-are-dot-files). However, Windows files consists of a name (before the dot) and a file type (after the dot), thus interpretting the "name" of the file as empty, and the file type as `htaccess`.

So how can this limitation be overcome on a Windows system? Windows has no problems copying and editing a file named `.htaccess` if it already exists, it's just renaming the file that causes problems.

**Solution 1**
It's possible to rename the file using the command prompt (previously DOS, for those who remember pre-windows times).

1. Browse to the root folder of your localhost Joomla installation (e.g. `c:\xampp\htdocs\myjoomla`)
2. Go to File - Open command prompt (or use this keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. You should see a black window with the text `C:\xampp\htdocs\myjoomla>_`, indicating the current folder location.
4. Type `rename htaccess.txt .htaccess` in order to rename the file (no confirmation is given, but the file is renamed)
5. Close the window (or type `exit`)

[image: Rename .htaccess file]

**Solution 2**
Another alternative is to copy an existing `.htaccess` from another Joomla installation (or download from an online Joomla installation). As mentioned earlier, the *nameless* file can be copied and edited without any problems by Windows.